# How can i split integer number in iphone application?

Tags: ios4

```
//string convert into integer

numberIntValue=[numberId intValue];
numberIntValue=16153;
```

How can  i split this integer number into `16`, `15` and `3`?

Comment: How you wish to divide it or on what parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger one=numberIntValue/1000;
NSInteger two=(numberIntValue%1000)/10;
NSInteger three=numberIntValue%10;
```