# Splitting a string into various combinations

Tags: matlab

I am in need of some direction on splitting a string into various combinations. Actually my requirement is to split an integer, but I guess those can't be split, that's why I've converted the integer into string.

For eg.
I've a string "123456"
I want to split it like

12 34 56

123 45 6

12 345 6

12 3 456

and like wise. One more problem is, the size of the string can be variable. As I told, these are actually integers, so it can have from 4 places to 7-8 places, and so will be the size of resultant string to be split into combinations.

I currently don't have any code to achieve it. I've just performed the simple splitting operation in the command box, but couldn't think of the way of achieving the required result. Please give me some direction on what I can do.

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is a but underspecified: How exactly shall you split it? Into how many / how large groups? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835747/how-can-i-split-integer-number-in-iphone-application for the general idea of extracting digit groups from itegers.

Comment: The link was helpful. Thanks
I want to split in variable lengths. Theres no specific length of group. Actually, I'll later compare the theoretical bit requirement of all the combination and the one having least will be used in further processing. As seen,

12 34 56 requires 14 bits
123 45 6 requires 16 bits
12 345 6 requires 15 bits
12 3 456 requires 15 bits
.In general, I'll follow the same format, i.e. at first, all the groups will be of same size. Then the first group will increase it size by one and others reduce accordingly and so on.
so out of this, I'll take the 1st combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can use the num2str() function to convert the integer value to a string.  Once you have converted the number to a string, you can then use the length() function to determine how many digits there are in the number.  You can then use the length of the string split up the number in various ways.  The example below only splits in groups of two, but you can adjust as desired.

```
val=123456;
str=num2str(val);
i=1;
k=1;
len=2;%split values into groups of 2
while(i<length(str)-1)
val(k)=str2num(str(i:i+len-1));
i=i+len;
k=k+1;
end
if(i<=length(str))
val(k)=str2num(str(i:end));%catches the remainder
end
```

Comment: This was useful. I guess with little editing, I can get what I want. Thanks.